Flutter Video Player: MediaCodecVideoRenderer Error on Android with ExoPlayer
I’m encountering an issue with Flutter’s video_player package while trying to play a video on Android. The video player fails to initialize with the following error:
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [1280, 720, 29.975233, ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma)], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)

Full Error Stack:
Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: start failed
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:2131)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:60)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:139)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1225)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1137)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:588)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1602)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1182)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1042)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:860)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.render(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1018)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1136)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:561)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398): Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):   androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [1280, 720, 29.975233, ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma)], [-1, -1])
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1144)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:588)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1602)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1182)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1042)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:860)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.render(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1018)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1136)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:561)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: start failed
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:2131)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:60)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:139)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1225)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1137)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 1398):       ... 11 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):   androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [1280, 720, 29.975233, ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma)], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:640)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):   Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [1280, 720, 29.975233, ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma)], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1144)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:588)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1602)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1182)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1042)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:860)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.render(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1018)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1136)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:561)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       ... 3 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: start failed
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:2131)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:60)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:139)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1225)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1137)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 1398):       ... 11 more

I suspect it has something to do with how the video is being decoded by the MediaCodec on the device, especially for H.264 (video/avc). The error suggests a codec issue or device-specific limitation.
Code:
Here is the code I’m using:
late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
bool isVideoInitialized = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initializeVideoPlayer();
}

void initializeVideoPlayer() async {
  try {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse("https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4"),
    )
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isVideoInitialized = true;
      });
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      log("Error: $error, StackTrace: $stackTrace");
    });
  } catch (e, st) {
    log("Error: $e, StackTrace: $st");
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
  disposeVideoPlayer();
  super.dispose();
}

disposeVideoPlayer() async {
  await _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  log("Video Player Disposed");
}

Environment:

Flutter version: 3.24.3
video_player package: Latest
Android device: MediaTek chipset

Steps I’ve Tried:

Tested different video URLs.
Tried using HLS format with VideoFormat.hls.
Removed the formatHint but still facing the same issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with MediaCodec on Android? Any solutions or workarounds would be appreciated!

I went through this issue but did'nt found any useful solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81804
